# Animation issue

Tags: animation

Using inverse kinematics I have run int an issue where when the leg moves the calf animation lags behind. It moves but not as much. I manually weighted everything, I removed all double vertices, I completely undid and redid every bone weight just to be sure there were no vertices assigned to more than one bone (if that would even cause an issue I was just troubleshooting at that point) and I cannot figure it out. The calf seems to be moving at about a quarter the pace it should be to keep up with the rest of the leg.

Comment: Hi. Please make your title specific to the issue you are having, instead of just the general topic.

Comment: Since we don't have the file, they are guesses at best, but do you have the bones parented to any controller objects or empties that would counteract the IK?